# How to convert "created_timestamp": 1553678246, to date dd: mm: yyyy format

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP(cast(ISSUE.body->>'created_timestamp' as int))::TIMESTAMP::date issue_creation_date
 from masters."ISSUE" as ISSUE
```

Comment: got the solution     
SELECT to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP(cast(ISSUE.body->>'created_timestamp' as int))::TIMESTAMP::date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') as issue_creation_date
from masters."ISSUE" as ISSUE;

Comment: This might help - `SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(1577094419);` Result: `2019-12-23 09:46:59+00` - see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9e286b0d3e17bac8a5657adca84528a5).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP(cast(ISSUE.body->>'created_timestamp' as int)),'dd:mm:yyyy') issue_creation_date from masters."ISSUE" as ISSUE
```